# What is the definition of integrability in the context of surface charges?

Tags: research-level, symmetry

In the usual covariant approach to the development of surface charges of an asymptotic symmetry group, one works with the linearized theory as this ensures that the charges are integrable.

I also read

> In the full interacting theory with prescribed asymptotics, the expressions are one-forms on solution space indexed by asymptotic symmetries and one has to face the question whether these one-forms are integrable, i.e. whether one can construct suitable "Hamiltonians" for them.

What is the meaning of integrable here?

Comment: Where is the quote taken from? Never mind, found it: page 4 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0213. Related post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78634/2451

Comment: I know it's late, but from what I've understood while reading on the topic of asymptotic symmetry, when you calculate surface charges, they are the surface integrals that involve the 'superpotential' given in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep--th/0111246 (equation 1.6 and onward). The expression contains usually a covariant derivative, a vector and some boundary terms (boundary conditions). Integrability just means that your integral won't diverge. Usually you are looking at the asymptotics (say $r\to\infty$), and you want that your integral doesn't have r dependance after the calculation (1/2)

Comment: Because if you have r in it, after putting $r\to\infty$ the expression will clearly diverge. That's mainly what I got from Kerr/CFT correspondence. (2/2)

Comment: Oh, also have you read http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0111246v2.pdf ? Look at the definition in (6.44), there the integration is given for AdS${}_3$. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you @dingo_d! I will go through the papers you suggested. PS - Its never too late!